# Azure DevOps pass parameter between release stages not build

Tags: azure-devops, azure-devops-rest-api

I have release pipeline and I would like to variable from stage 1 to stage 2 but only keep this in this specific release not modifying release definition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Stage 1

```
Install-Module VSTeam -Scope CurrentUser -Force
Set-VSTeamAccount –Account $(Acct) -PersonalAccessToken $(PAT)
Get-VSTeamRelease -ProjectName "$(System.TeamProject)" -Id $(Release.ReleaseId) -Raw
$r.variables.test.value = 'Set In Stage 1'
$r.variables | Add-Member NoteProperty temp([PSCustomObject]@{value='Created in Stage 1'})
Update-VSTeamRelease -ProjectName "$(System.TeamProject)" -Id $(Release.ReleaseId) -Release $r -Force
```

In Stage 2

```
Write-Host $(Test)
Write-Host $(Temp)
```

Found in 
http://donovanbrown.com/post/Passing-variables-from-stage-to-stage-in-Azure-DevOps-release